# Is there a way to rewind while recording a screencast

Tags: camstudio

I'm working to make a screencast with http://camstudio.org/ . In case I mis speak while making the recording, is there a way to rewind a few seconds , rather than starting over at the beginning?

Comment: I would probably record the screencast video, then dub over it later. It allows you to have a more fluid script and more professional sound, in my opinion. But, as @Ramhound says, this will obviously require tools beyond CamStudio.

Comment: @Ramhound, Could you recommend the tools needed beyond cam studio?

Comment: @Ramhound, If you don't want to name particular software , how about recommending an approach to being able to make editable screencasts.

Comment: @user61629 - Good luck!

Comment: I found the following video helpful. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiQr5efiW7o